# gtk_window_fullscreen problem

Tags: fullscreen, gtk

I need in full screen window functional in my gtk+ application. I try to use `gtk_window_fullscreen(GtkWindow* Window)`:

I have function:

```
static void
full_screen(MainWin *mw)
{
    gtk_window_fullscreen((GtkWindow*)mw);
}
```

When i try to call this function i see error:

```
Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_window_fullscreen: assertion `GTK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed
```

Where MainWin:

```
typedef struct _MainWin MainWin; 

typedef struct _MainWin 
{ 
    GtkWindow parent; 
    GtkWidget* scroll; 
    GtkWidget* box; 
    GtkWidget *toolbar; 
    gboolean full_screen; 
};
```

What's wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You're (still) trying to weirdly *subclass* `GtkWindow` for some reason. You can't do that like that, where did you get this idea?

You need to have a widget pointer:

```
GtkWindow *window;
```

Then create the window using `gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)`.